# get value of variable from source code in jasmine spec file

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am working with jasmine and running it on terminal. My javascript function not returning any value, instead it sets some variables with some values. How can i test values of variables are properly set in my function ?

I was trying to do it using spyOn on variable but it's throwing error telling that `obj` is not defined:

```
 var toCleanObject = function(obj){
    for (const i in obj) {
        if (obj[i] === "" || obj[i] === false) {
          delete obj[`${i}`];
        }
    }
}
```

for below function if i am passing `obj` as `{id:1,rank:3,name:""}`
in `spec`. I need to try if `obj` becomes `{id:1,rank:3}` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not spyOn anything for this particular case. You call the function with some object and after the call the object should have changed to the desired form. just assert

```
const obj = {id:1,rank:3,name:""};
toCleanObject(obj);
expect(obj).toEqual({id:1,rank:3})
```

Comment: Please check now. I have modified my answer.